# Repository Pattern with IoC

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, inversion-of-control

I am building a WPF application (storage system), which would be running for a very long time and therefore I am interested in what option should I go with when using Entity Framework with Repository Patterns.

What I did, is that I have separated my Data Access Layer (DAL) into a separate class library referenced by the main project. For the technologies, I have decided to use Entity Framework 6 & SQLite database (plus SQLite plugins for EF).

In the main project, except for other things (such as Prism) I am also using Unity for IoC while working with my ViewModels.

This is how I am registering my repository under **Bootstrapper.cs** class:

```
Container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

The reason why I have decided to use `TransientLifetimeManager` was to make sure, that this class is re-created every time ViewModel is created and thus ensuring that new data is being fetched from the database.

Here is a (oversimplified) repository with only two methods:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    UserLevel TryLoginUser(User user);
    string RegisterNewUser(User user);
    void Dispose();
}
```

With sample implementation:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public enum UserLevel { Regular, Supervisor, Admin, Invalid };

    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public UserRepository()
    {
        _context = new DataContext();
    }

    public UserLevel TryLoginUser(User user)
    {
        return UserLevel.Invalid;
    }

    public string RegisterNewUser(User user)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What users will be doing is, that they will be switching between 2 (or three) main windows thorough the lifetime of an application. In order to make sure, that the database data from Entity Framework is in sync with the database, what I have decided to do is to initialize new `DataContext` in the constructor of the method itself (which reloads the data).

When I have explored the memory usage while navigating back and forth between my windows (and calling various repositories), I have noticed that the memory usage starts to go up, which means that, clearly, there is something wrong with my method of initializing and injecting `Repositories`.

Finally, in regards to this topic, I have also tried to somehow register my `DataContext.cs` (which is very simple and just inherits from **DbContext**) so that it could be injectable into the repositories; however I had even problems registering it (as it lacks interface definition, Unity didn't allow me to register it).

I would highly appreciate any help or recommendations in this matter.

Comment: you have registered implementation for IUserRepository: `RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>`. Client classes don't need to know that UserRepository implementation works with `DataContext`. So why register it anywhere?

Comment: also: `public enum UserLevel` is a nested class of UserRepository. interface  IUserRepository uses that enum. IUserRepository and UserRepository are coupled (every time projects needs IUserRepository, it also must reference UserRepository)

Comment: So you are saying that my current method of creating new `DataContext` within repositories is correct? So where can I have a memory leak then?

Comment: DbContext implements IDisposable. I suppose UserRepository should do it as well and dispose its resources.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041113/c-sharp-entity-framework-correct-use-of-dbcontext-class-inside-your-repository